# Dynamic Linq Query from Datatable for Pivot Table

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, datatable, pivot

I have been struggling with this problem for a while and was wondering if I can get some help.

I have the following items:

```
Datatable inputdata = //Data from large scale SQL query
var rowvals = (from x in reportattrs.AsEnumerable()
                       where x.Field<long>("COLFORREPORT") == 0 && x.Field<long>("VALUEFIELD") == 0
                       orderby x.Field<long>("ORDERDISPLAY")
                       select new { Name = x.Field<object>("FIELDNAME") });
var colvals = (from x in reportattrs.AsEnumerable()
                       where x.Field<long>("COLFORREPORT") == 1 && x.Field<long>("VALUEFIELD") == 0
                       orderby x.Field<long>("ORDERDISPLAY")
                       select new { Name = x.Field<object>("FIELDNAME") });
var datavals = (from x in reportattrs.AsEnumerable()
                        where x.Field<long>("COLFORREPORT") == 1 && x.Field<long>("VALUEFIELD") == 1
                        orderby x.Field<long>("ORDERDISPLAY")
                        select new { Name = x.Field<object>("FIELDNAME") });
```

Rowvals are the attributes of the table that we want to filter for in rows, colvals are the column values for the pivot table, datavals are the data sums

What I want to do is create my own custom pivot table routine that allows me to filter and layer in a more sophisticated method.

I am able to get the specific distinct values of one row:

```
foreach(object val in rowvals){
var distinctValues = dsValues.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(row => new {
                                attribute1_name = row.Field<string>(val)
                             })
                            .Distinct();
}
```

How I can filter out for each value in combination (for a variable number rows and cols) is difficult for me.  Not only that, I need to select all the values for each value column so I can aggregate it how I see fit.

Any help would be greatly!

Thanks
Jon

Comment: So I have created a set of functions that manually inspect the table and perform the aggregation, recursive dictionary function, but I would like to see if I can linqify this process.  I don't know if the recursive function helps - should I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not absolutely clear how your input data looks like; since you want to build pivot table I assume that it can be presented as dataset like that (if not it should be converted to the tabular view acceptable for pivot operation):

```
col1 | col2 | val1 
-------------------
 C1  |  R1  |  1 
 C1  |  R2  |  2
 C1  |  R1  |  3
 C2  |  R1  |  4
```

and desired pivot table is something like that (lets use 'col1' values for pivot table columns, and 'col2' values for rows, and SUM of val1 for values):

```
     |  C1  |  C2 
-----------------
 R1  |  4   |  4
 R2  |  2   |  0 (or empty)
```

Data for pivot table like that can be easily calculated by [NReco PivotData](http://www.nrecosite.com/pivot_data_library_net.aspx) library with just several lines of code (disclaimer: I'm an author of this library):

```
// group and calculate measures
var pivotData = new PivotData(
    new string[] {"col1","col2"},
    new SumAggregatorFactory("val1"),
    new DataTableReader(t) );
// get pivot table model for accessing columns/rows/values in easy way
var pivotTable = new PivotTable(
    new []{"col2"}, // row dimension(s)
    new []{"col1"}, // column dimension(s)
    pivotData );

var rowLabels = pivotTable.RowKeys;
var colLabels = pivotTable.ColumKeys;
var cellValue = pivotTable[0, 0].Value; // R1 + C1: 4
var grandTotal = pivotTable[null,null].Value; // 10
```

Also you can specify several columns for rows/columns and can calculate several measures. Feel free to contact me if something is not clear.

Comment: Is your library free for download?

Comment: @Jon NReco.PivotData nuget package (which classes are used in the code snippet from above) can be used for free in a single-deployment projects (except SaaS).